# turn 50amp 240v into a subpanel with 30amp and 15amp

Tags: electrical, subpanel

I have a 50amp 240v line that came with the house that is for my oven (comes from the main panel). I'm getting a new oven that needs 30amp 240v and a speed oven that needs 15amp 240v.

Can I take my existing 50amp 240v line and turn that into a subpanel where there is 1 30amp 240v circuit and 1 15amp 240v circuit?

Comment: Should be able to.  Panels require about 30 inches on the sides and about 36 inches in front of open space for working on them.

Comment: Can you get us make and model information for the two ovens? It may very well be the case that you can connect both of them to the same circuit *without* a subpanel at all

Comment: Upvoted TPE's comment - it is allowed via code if it's allowed in the manual.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Interesting comment, I suppose if they are both hard-wired and don't require external over-current protection, it could work and be code legal, you know more about this than me.  But if they are plug/outlet connected, I see no code legal way to do it w/o a sub-panel.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel They are wolf oven and microwave and from talking with wolf they must be on a dedicated circuit for the warranty to be considered valid.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box where the existing oven wiring terminates @odyth?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel not without removing the current oven that is there. I remember it being a junction box and the oven wires were wired directly into the 4 gauge aluminum wires and secured with wire nuts.

Comment: @odyth -- were there 3 or 4 wires coming out of the wall?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel that is a great question...if it ends up being 3 then this won't work huh? it needs 4 for that neutral and ground? I just assumed it had 4 because all the 240v wiring i have done has had 4

Comment: @odyth -- yeah, if the existing circuit is 3 wire than you're in a bit of a pickle.  (also: Wolf is stupid for making a dedicated circuit a warranty requirement, if you ask me)